# Combine Columns (January, February, March, etc.. into one column)

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to combine months in the column into rows with the year. Here I have the months written out as January, February, and March and the years as the rows.:

Year,  January, February, March 
2017,    1, 2, 3 
2018,    1, 2, 3 
2019,    1, 2, 3

---

I want to combine those into a date format written below:

---

Date,  Value

2017-01-01,   1 
2017-02-01,   2 
2017-03-01,   3 
2018-01-01,   1 
2018-02-01,   2 
2018-03-01,   3

So far I have tried the iloc method but I cannot figure out how to get it into the dataframe that I want.

Any help would be appreciated.

for i in range(len(df)): 
y=df.iloc[i] 
j.append(y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = df.set_index(['Year'])
df
    January February  March
Year            
2017    1     2       3
2018    1     2       3
2019    1     2       3
```

Converting months in words to int

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df.columns), format='%B').dt.month
df
        1   2   3
Year            
2017    1   2   3
2018    1   2   3
2019    1   2   3
```

Use [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to get "column as a row"

```
   Year level_1 0
0   2017    1   1
1   2017    2   2
2   2017    3   3
3   2018    1   1
4   2018    2   2
5   2018    3   3
6   2019    1   1
7   2019    2   2
8   2019    3   3
```

Then you can get `Date` by concatenating and do the necessary formatting

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'].astype(str)
                            + '-' + df['level_1'].astype(str)
                            + '-' + str(1))
df = (df
      .rename(columns={0:'Value'})
      .drop(['Year', 'level_1'], axis=1)
      .reindex(['Date', 'Value'], axis=1)
     )
df

        Date    Value
0   2017-01-01  1
1   2017-02-01  2
2   2017-03-01  3
3   2018-01-01  1
4   2018-02-01  2
5   2018-03-01  3
6   2019-01-01  1
7   2019-02-01  2
8   2019-03-01  3
```

Comment: This helped out a ton. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! As it helped, consider accepting/upvoiting the anser

Comment: Im new to stack overflow so I upvoted the answer but I need 15 reputation points for people to see it. But thank you again!